# Unable to have Internet Connection with Huawei E367, Mobile Broadband

Tags: 11.10, broadband

**My dmesg, some extra at the head and tail:**

```
[  146.345953] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[  146.352066] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[  146.373036] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[  146.373042] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[  148.066397] EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro,commit=0
[  148.319003] init: plymouth-stop pre-start process (1501) terminated with status 1
[  226.325840] PPP BSD Compression module registered
[  226.364372] PPP Deflate Compression module registered
[  314.192053] usb 1-5: new high speed USB device number 4 using ehci_hcd
[  319.517640] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[  319.541413] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
```

The lines starting with "PPP" means that my device E367 can connect to the operator's network via USB-2.0 in Thinkpad X60. The device get an ip, so after running `ifconfig` we get:

```
ppp0      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol  
          inet addr:10.20.38.151  P-t-P:10.64.64.64  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:11 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:12 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:3 
          RX bytes:158 (158.0 B)  TX bytes:269 (269.0 B)
```

The packet loss is however 100% when I try to ping, for instance `ping google.com`.

I am not sure where the problem is. I know that the thing is

1. NOT reboot problem, since I have rebooted my system now 18 times with different configs.
2. should NOT be in the hardware, since I can replicate it with two Thinkpad Lenovo X60s with clean Ubuntu 11.10s; however worked for some reason in **11.10 beta**.
3. NOT a softblock or hardblock problem, since I can see it with `rfkill list`.
4. NOT a blacklist problem, since I have nothing in my personal blacklists and the default blacklists are not changed.
5. My Dongle E367 works, since I verified it in the operator's shop with XP and Windows 7

Pieces of information about the connection that does not get internet although it should:[image]

**How can you use Huawei E367 with your Mobile Broadband Successfully?**

Comment: You only have 40 reputation, how can you give a 100 bounty?

Comment: @GregTreleaven Once you give a bounty the reputation is deducted immediately.

Comment: I ordered the CD 10.04 and the CD base to X60 to test whether the problem occurs in 10.04. I get also X60s on 11.11. so I have more computers to debug the problem. It takes me now  at least the given about two weeks to have sufficient infrastructures with me to push the case forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Solve your problem, I have two options, both are working the same. Whichever you like install it. It's easy to configure and use.

You can find the details as bellow.

1 ]

GNOME PPP is an easy to use graphical dialup connection configuring and dialing tool with system tray icon support.

It uses GNOME/GTK+ for its graphical interface and integrates well in GNOME desktop environment, but it can be used in other environments.

It also uses WvDial dialer as its backend, providing simple configuration via config files. You can also use plain wvdial if you don't have X running.

2]

KPPP is a modem dialer for connecting to a dial-up Internet Service Provider. It displays statistics and accounting information to help users keep track of connection costs.

This package is part of the KDE 4 networking module.

You can find both Apppication on Ubuntu Software Center. both have Graphical Environment. So, you can easily configure and dial-up.

Comment: That homepage looks dead.

Comment: Gnome ppp asks username. What is it for mobile broadband? I do not seem to have any username with my broadband, only phonenumber and password.

Comment: your phone number is u r username

Comment: I get the following log after an unsuccessful attempt: [code]--> WvDial: Internet dialer version 1.61
--> Cannot set information for serial port.
--> Initializing modem.
--> Sending: ATZ
OK
--> Sending: ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
ERROR
--> Bad init string.
--> Cannot open /dev/ttyUSB0: No such file or directory
--> Cannot open /dev/ttyUSB0: No such file or directory[/code]

Comment: I wonder whether the given approach really is the source of the problem, since I can get to the network but only the internet does not work. There must be something internal, probably in drivers where the problem is. I told me that the given problem is very probably an unsolved bug in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

"How To:connect Huawei e367 modem with Ubuntu" - http://techspear.com/2011/08/connecting-huawei-e367-modem-with-ubuntu/

Comment: I know the link. The given problem is not the problem here.

Comment: you can download Ubuntu software center

Comment: @DeepakRajput What do you mean? I do not get your point about Ubuntu software center, since it is default in 11.10.

Answer (score 0):

I got one tip from ubuntu-fi-freenode-irc that umount the internal memory of the dongle by `sudo umount /dev/sr1`, but I get `umount: /dev/sr1: not found`. Ubuntu recognizes the device as CDROM.

**How can you umount the given memory that is recognized as CDROM?**

I am not sure how the given thing should solve the problem, but let's at least try.